# How to logout user from .net core 3.1 application using AWS Cognito and OIDC middleware

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I'm using AWS Cognito for user authentication in .NET Core 3.1 MVC application. I'm trying to logout user but it throws an error "InvalidOperationException: Cannot redirect to the end session endpoint, the configuration may be missing or invalid. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.SignOutAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.SignOutAsync(HttpContext context, string scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)"

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to all who looked it up + @Tore Nestenius. The "logout_uri", at the end of this link, should be exactly (including "/" at the end) as it's in your UserPool > App integration > App client settings > Sign out URL(s). In my case, just http**s**://localhost:XXXX/ --> "https://XXXX.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=XXXX&logout_uri=https://localhost:XXXX/"
The project in VS should run as "https://localhost:XXXX/" (right click project > Properties > Debug > App URL: https://localhost:XXXX/)

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Authorization/AccessDenied")
 .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
     options.ResponseType = "code";
     options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["AWS:MetadataAddress"];
     options.ClientId = Configuration["AWS:ClientId"];
     options.ClientSecret = Configuration["AWS:ClientSecret"];
     options.SaveTokens = true;

     // Logout
     options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
        {
          OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = context =>
           {
             var logoutUri = Configuration["AWS:LogOutFullPath"];
             //logoutUri: "https://XXXX.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/logout?client_id=XXXX&logout_uri=http://localhost:XXXX/logout"
             context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);

             context.HandleResponse();
             return Task.CompletedTask;
           }
         };

HomeController/Logout
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // <-- no error if used alone but it doesn't remove cookies
  await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme); // <-- throws error

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Did the await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) stop failing for you?  I'm having the same issue with OpenID Connect.

Comment: Hi Travis, the code above should work. The issue was with the "logout_uri" setting in AWS UserPool. Please also see the response below provided by Tore.

Answer (score 2):

A proper logout should look like this:

```
    public async Task DoLogout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

The issue is that you are not supposed to return anything from this action method, because calling Signout will in it self prepare a response of it own. If you now return a redirect, then you overwrite the response from SignOutAsync´.

For proper signout you should also consider making it a HTTP-Post operation, like

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

See this question for more details:

•   [Should login and logout action have CSRF protection?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/62769)